# Selective execution of .xinitrc for different DEs/WMs?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, window-manager, i3-wm

I recently finished my GNOME customisation and always have i3 on my machine because I like having the option to use it. I recently hit a roadblock when I realised if I put in a .xinitrc file to set my i3 wallpaper (among other things), that GNOME would use it too when I initialised X. How can I get GNOME to ignore my .xinitrc file or get i3 to do these things on its own without a .xinitrc?
I am on ubuntu 19.10 with GNOME 3.34.1 running on GDM.

Comment: Whether `.xinitrc` is invoked should depend on *how* the session is started, not *which* session is started - see for example [Difference between .xinitrc, .xsession and .xsessionrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281923/65304). If you need different behavior for different sessions started via `startx`/`xinit`, then I guess you could test the value of `DESKTOP_SESSION`?

Comment: how would i go about using that with my .xinitrc for i3?